# Why does this collection is a set and what is this symbol?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

My question is quite simple, I'm trying to understand why $Hom_{sets}(X,Y)$ is a set and what is this symbol $Y^X$?

> **Definition 1.12.** A category $\mathbf{C}$ is called *locally small* if for all objects $X, Y$ in $\mathbf{C}$, the collection $\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{C}}(X,Y) = \{f \in \mathbf{C}_1 \mid f : X \longrightarrow Y \}$ is a *set* (called a *hom-set*).
>
> Many of the large categories we want to consider are in fact locally small. $\mathbf{Sets}$ is locally small since $\color{purple}{\textrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}}(X,Y) = Y^X}$, the *set* of all functions from $X$ to $Y$. Similarly, $\mathbf{Pos}$, $\mathbf{Top}$, and $\mathbf{Group}$ are all locally small (is $\mathbf{Cat}$?), and, of course, any small category is locally small.

I'm sorry, I'm sure this should be a silly question, but I only know very basic set theory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the notation mean?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm sorry, please see the picture I've just sent.

Comment: The symbol $Y^X$ usually denotes the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$, (in this case it does). If $X$ and $Y$ are cardinals then $Y^X$ is a cardinal, and it is the cardinality of the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$

Comment: Just a piece of advice: I don't think it's a particularly good idea to learn category theory with just a basic understanding of basic set theory...

Comment: Are you wondering what axioms prove that $Hom(X,Y)$ is a set? And the identity in the picture above tells you what $Y^X$ is; it's the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @5xum why? I'm not having any problems with category theory so far, just few doubts sometimes. Do you think in more advanced levels things can be more difficult for someone with basic set theory?

Comment: @user42912 well, you just encountered a problem you would not have if you would have more background knowledge. It's just a piece of advice, I think you may encounter more problems later on.

Comment: @5xum do you know a good reference book to get this background?

Comment: Not really, all my basic set theory came from books written in Slovenian...

Comment: I join @5xum in the suggestion that you learn some basic set theory first. It can help you clear the doubts that you have, and the doubts that you don't even know that you have. In particular, it would have solved this question for you. The reason it's needed is that you're not studying category theory as a foundation for mathematics (i.e. the primitive objects of your universe *are* sets, not groups or whatever), but rather category theory formalized in set theory. (As evident by the screenshot that you posted.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $X,Y$ are fixed then we can regard a function as its graph, rather than an ordered triplet (as the praxis of category theory goes).

This graph is always a subset of $X\times Y$.

Therefore the collection $\{f\subseteq X\times Y\mid f\text{ is a function from }X\text{ to }Y\}$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(X\times Y)$.

So we have that:

1. $X\times Y$ is a set. It has a power set.
2. Therefore $\mathcal P(X\times Y)$ is a set. Its definable collections are sets.
3. Therefore $\{f\subseteq X\times Y\mid f\text{ is a function from }X\text{ to }Y\}$ is a set. We denote this set as $Y^X$ in set theory.

So if $X$ and $Y$ are sets the above shows that $Y^X=\hom_{\bf Sets}(X,Y)$ is also a set; and thus $\bf Sets$ is locally small.